# chrome.windows.onFocusChanged never returns chrome.windows.WINDOW_ID_NONE in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu, google-chrome-extension, ubuntu-14.04, ubuntu-unity

The official [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#event-onFocusChanged) states that when no Chrome windows have focus, I should get an event with a windowId of WINDOW_ID_NONE(-1). However, I can not cause this to happen in my setup, using Ubuntu 14.04 with the default Unity DWM.

In my attached screenshot: [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpsF5.jpg)

, I have two Chrome windows open across two monitors, one is a normal session, the other is a inspected view of my extension's background page. I have the Trash window of my file browser clicked on and in focus, yet I didn't get the expected onFocusChangedEvent.

```
chrome.windows.onFocusChanged.addListener(function(window){
    if(window == chrome.windows.WINDOW_ID_NONE){
        console.log("not in focus!");
    }else{
        console.log("in focus!");
    }
});
```

Is this a bug or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Looks like a bug, yes.

Comment: Works fine on ArchLinux, KDE & Xorg. Bug reproduced on Ubuntu 14.04 & KDE.

Comment: Any idea where upstream this should be reported to? Also, if someone would like to write an answer and I will accept it.